# Problem when importing PySCIPOpt. AttributeError: type object 'pyscipopt.scip.Expr' has no attribute '__div__'

Tags: python, interface, scip

I want to use python interface for `SCIP`; I installed `PySCIPOpt` following [these steps](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

I'm using `SCIP7`, `PySCIPOpt` 3, and python 3.7. `SCIP`'s interactive shell alone works well. However, when I try to `import pyscipopt`, I get the following error

> File "src/pyscipopt/scip.pyx", line 1, in init pyscipopt.scip
> AttributeError: type object 'pyscipopt.scip.Expr' has no attribute '**div**'

My operating system is Linux Mint 19.2

I tried to test the installation as suggested, and I get the errors in the image[image]

Comment: did you try [testing the installation](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md#testing-new-installation) as suggested on the github page?

Comment: Yes, and I get the following errors  in the image above

Comment: Hi, did you solve it? I meet the same problem today :(

Comment: No, I didn't! I'm using ZIMPL with SCIP, instead of PySCIPOpt; and I must say that it's very un-practical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be an update in cython. It should be fixed in the current master of PySCIPOpt. See also https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/397

Comment: Thank you! Installing the new version of PySCIPOpt solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

python is very sensitive for syntax , Like upper case etc..

so may be you try :

import PySCIPOpt instate  import pyscipopt

Comment: The syntax is correct, all in lower case according to the Github page; if I do what u suggested I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySCIPOpt'